# How to use different short description in shop page and in product page in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, description

What I would like to have is the sentence "Entre em contacto connosco para saber preços Aqui" just in product page, not in shop page. Please take a look in this page: http://www.kepaweleurope.com/shop/soutien-mamoplastia-85/

Does anybody can help me?

Thanks in advance
Miguel

Comment: Maybe try WooCommerce support?

Answer (score 6):

The short description template is /templates/single-product/short-description.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * Single product short description
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post;

if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) return;
?>
<div itemprop="description">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
</div>
```

You can override this (or any woo template) : http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/  by copying the file into your theme... so `woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php`.  Then you can edit it as you like.

**EDIT:** If I understand your question you would do this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single product short description
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post;

?>
<div itemprop="description">
    Entre em contacto connosco para saber preços Aqui
</div>
```

Or you could filter `woocommerce_short_description`.  Or you could define your own `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt()` function which is pluggable, or remove it entirely from its hook.  There really are many ways to do this, but the template override tends to be the simplest to understand.

**EDIT: Here's a very basic example of how to filter the short description** (and in general filtering anything is always the same process)

**Edit again: this goes in your theme's functions.php**

```
function wpa_98244_filter_short_description( $desc ){
    global $product;

    if ( is_single( $product->id ) )
        $desc .= ' add some extra text to the short description';

    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'wpa_98244_filter_short_description' );
```

Comment: Hello Helga, Tks for your help.

Comment: Hello Helga, Tks for your help. Let me see if I understand. The simplest way is to override. I did, and know I think I have to edit the file. The question is what do I need to do to have what I want? Can you give me something more? Thanks in advance, Miguel

Comment: Check my edit. Otherwise, clarify your question.

Comment: Hello Helga. I'm back to this issue, because I was in another project. Thanks for your support so far. What I need is to have the short description like the normal woocommerce theme (I would like not to have the "Entre em contacto connosco para saber preços Aqui"). In the product page I would like to have the normal short description plus "Entre em contacto connosco para saber preços Aqui" instead of the prices that I have already deleted. I'm not sure if I was clear enough... Thanks in advance. Miguel

Comment: So just copy the original template and add "Entre em contacto" to it. What about my solution isn't working for you?

Comment: No, It dosen't work for me because if I use it I don't have the short description on the product page and I have "Entre em contacto" on the shop page. I need short description in both pages and "Entre em contacto" only in product page.  I don't know if I'm clear....Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question or perhaps even ask a new (different) question. I have answered the question as originally asked.  FYI- the short description displays by default on the product page, unless your theme has modified it.

Comment: I have edited my answer again to show how to filter the description in lieu of editing templates.

Comment: Helga, please tell me where do I put the filter inside the short description? Thanks in advance.

Comment: <div itemprop="description">
    Is it here?
</div>

Comment: Dear Helga, I edit the file and I did the following change, but it's not working:<?php
/**
 * Single product short description
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
global $post;
if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) return;
?>
<div itemprop="description">
function wpa_98244_filter_short_description( $desc ){
    global $product;
    if ( is_single( $product->id ) )
        $desc .= ' add some extra text to the short description';
    return $desc;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'wpa_98244_filter_short_description' );
</div>

Comment: The filter goes in your theme's functions.php file

Comment: Hello Helga. Thanks for your support. It works fine.

Comment: After all that, don't forget to accept my solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this thing with WordPress database for the product page.
in this code, you can put your own short description. I have also used condition. you can change it as per your requirement. this code you need to put in function.php file of your theme.

```
function My_short_description(){
        global $post,$wpdb,$woocommerce;
        $your_short_description = "My Description";
        $id = get_the_id();
        $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
        $query = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_excerpt FROM {$prefix}posts WHERE ID={$id}");
        if($query)
        {
            $woocommerce_page_short_description = $query->post_excerpt;
            if($woocommerce_page_short_description=="" && $woocommerce_page_short_description==null)
            {
                echo $your_short_description;
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'My_short_description', 40 );
```